# Is there a way to make flake8 ignore a violation in a specific circumstance?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, flake8

I'm using the pandas package in Python and I'm working in visual studio code. I regularly use queries on dataframes, which can reference variable names in the external scope like this

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [10, 20]})
query_value = 20
print(df.query('b == @query_value'))
```

which would produce roughly this output

```
    a    b
1   2   20
```

Flake8 sees an `F841` violation (local variable assigned but never used) in this case because `query_value` is referenced inside a string. Is there a way for me to configure flake8 (or a vscode extension specifically) to ignore `F841` violations only when the variable name appears preceded by `@` within a string somewhere in the file?

I know I can do `# noqa: f841` to ignore violations in a line and ignore violations per-file with a command line argument, but these aren't what I want. I want to ignore `F841` only when I've used a variable correctly in a pandas query.

Comment: does flake8 allow you to write a reject/accept filter function

Comment: I haven't found that documented, hence the question

Answer (score 1):

There's a suggestion on the [flake8 issue tracker](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8/issues/1315) of a way to do this that doesn't cause a F841 violation.

```py
query_value = 20
print(df.query('b == @q', local_dict={'q': query_value}))
```

It's a bit more verbose, though.

Comment: Thanks, I'd missed this. Definitely understand why they want to catch this kind of problem out of the box, just hoping for something I can configure in my use case. Not sure I want to add a dict-valued argument to 181 queries across 8 files...